# How to delete multiple dynamically allocated arrays in a single delete statement?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, delete-operator

If I have 3 pointers to double :

```
rdf1 = new double [n];

rdf2 = new double [n];

rdf3 = new double [n];
```

I want to delete them with a single **delete** statement. something like :

```
delete [] rdf1,rdf2,rdf3;
```

What's the right way to do it ?

Comment: Would you accept deleting them with no delete statements? `std::vector<double> rdf1(n), rdf2(n), rdf3(n);`

Comment: you can write a macro to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is syntactically correct:

```
delete [] rdf1,rdf2,rdf3;
```

More unfortunately, it doesn't do what you think it does. It treats `,` as a [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), thus eventually deleting only `rdf1` (since operator `delete` has precedence over operator `,`).

You ***have to*** write separate `delete []` expressions to get the expected behavior.

```
delete [] rdf1;
delete [] rdf2;
delete [] rdf3;
```

Answer (score 8):

To be fair, you can do it as a single *statement*, just not as a single invocation of the `delete []` operator:

```
(delete [] rdf1, delete [] rdf2, delete [] rdf3);
```

But why in the world do you care whether it is one statement or three?

Comment: +1, just what I wanted to say! `delete` is not a statement, it's an operator (which is part of the delete-expression). The parentheses are redundant though.

Comment: I didn't want to make it complex. Just wondered if it's possible to do the same with a single delete operator.
Thanx for your answer

Answer (score 6):

No it is not the right way. You have to call `delete []` on each of the pointers separately.

The standard form of `operator delete[]` will take only one parameter.

```
delete [] rdf1;
delete [] rdf2;
delete [] rdf3;
```

I always follow one principle that the code I write should be easily understandable by one who works on it after me. So rather than doing this with any fancy constructs I would do it the more commonly known way(which is above).